# CREATE view in Geoserver based on current timestamp

Tags: geoserver, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use the "Create NEW SQL view" function in Geoserver to create a new view, in which I wish to show a subset of records from a table in MSSQL based on a value in another table. 
I have two layers in the same MSSQL DATABASE one with some geometries ("LER_REQUEST_MAP") and another with some needed information ("LER_REQUEST_V2"). One of the informations in the later is an ESRI based timestamp field called "DIG_PERIOD_FROM".

I wish to use my view to:

a) join these two tables (INNER JOIN?), so that I get the information on DIG_Period_FROM to my geometry layer (LER_REQUEST_MAP) without compromising the original table.

b) SELECT * from "the new joined table" where the field DIG_PERIOD_FROM > CURRENT_DATE

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can create a view based on anything table(s) you like assuming you have permission to see them. I expect you will end up with something like:

```
select * from table1,table2 where table1.id = table2.id and digperiod > GETDATE();
```

Comment: Hi iant. Thanks that helps me some of tthe way. When I try a version of your code corrected to my tables I get an error message saying "The column 'OBJECTID' was specified multiple times for 'vtable'." And that is true. There is OBJECTID's in both tables (they are not corresponding). How can I get pass this, without altering the original tables?

Comment: don't select OBJECTID  from both or rename one of them if you actually need both

Comment: How do I write into my SQL statement that I wish to only have OBJERCTID from one table. I would very much like not to make any changes (what so ever) to the original tables, but make all the adjustments in the SQL Query.

Comment: select table1.objectid, table1.geom,....,table2.attribute1,table2.attribute2... from table1, table2 ...

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm. It always seems simple afterwards :)